# Will Java code be terminated in the middle if server is down suddenly

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic

Let say i have a java function with 1000 lines of codes and it is deployed on the weblogic.

Will there be a chance that code is running & terminated at line X of 1000 lines if the PC or Weblogic is shutdown suddenly (i.e force shutdown)?

If yes, is there any possible way to "run" the rest of the code (from X+1 to 1000) when the server is resumed.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a server stability issue than a programming issue. If a server needs to go down, you can always shutdown the application first in a safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

> Will there be a chance that code is running & terminated at line X of 1000 lines if the PC or Weblogic is shutdown suddenly (i.e force shutdown)?

**Yes**.

> If yes, is there any possible way to "run" the rest of the code (from X+1 to 1000) when the server is resumed.

You would have to implement such a mechanism, and it would then need to "reset" to some point before `X` and then resume the transaction. Although, your implementation could be a Rabbit MQ topic with durable messages. The more typical configuration (in my experience) involves running multiple Weblogic servers in a cluster, and failing over to another member of that cluster in this scenario (and in combination with durable queues).

Comment: Thanks, the function is actually running in a cluster & we find that the code is sometimes running half during failover/server down. With MQ, can we guarentee the whole code can run completely (Not familiar with it)?

Comment: Your question is still quite vague; servers can crash at any time. You need to design your code to fail fast **and** to deal with failures in general. You might also find adding additional tracing to your code can help find the sources of failures.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your code is doing, it could be interrupted at any time by an external failure.  The JRE itself is stateless; there is no automatic way to resume at a certain point.  The code itself must be designed to be 'restartable'.  That is, it must save state to some external, durable service. If this code is modifying external resources (calling web service, databases, ...) it must also somehow synchronize its saved state with the external resource on restart.

RabbitMQ can help with some of the aspects -- it's a guaranteed delivery message bus.  It can insure that messages to external resource will be delivered.  It could also synchronize between multiple running instances of your code, if you wanted a distributed, cluster-aware application, which is difficult to do.